# C basics, if the input is not a positive integer, ask for a new input

Tags: c

i am trying to make this basic program:
-It asks for an input

A : if it is a positive integer, thats good, and i can use that on the second part of the program.

B : if the input is not a positive integer, it will ask for a new input until it gets a positive integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        int number;
    
        printf("Please enter a positive integer:\n");
    
        do {
                scanf("%d", &number);
    
        }
    
    
        while (number >= 0);
    
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Right now you wrote a program that does the exact opposite of what you want. What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the loop condition backwards - you're supposed to continue looping as long as the input is not a positive integer:

```
do {
    scanf("%d", &number);
}
while (number <= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First [read full lines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), as invalid input (like e.g. letters) will not be removed from the input buffer. Then parse the input using `sscanf`. Then use the `%u` format to parse `unsigned int` values Lastly *always* check [what `sscanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Also remember to add a check for zero. And if the user wanted to break out of the input loop, possibly exiting the program.

Putting it together it could be something like this:

```
unsigned number;
char number_buffer[32];

printf("Please enter a positive integer:\n");
while fgets(number_buffer, sizeof number_buffer, stdin) != NULL)
{
    if (sscanf(number_buffer, "%u", &number) == 1 && number > 0)
    {
        // Successfully read non-negative and non-zero number, end loop
        break;
    }

    // Invalid input, ask the user again
    printf("Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer (not negative, not zero):\n");
}

if (feof(stdin) || ferror(stdin))
{
    // The user pressed the EOF keyboard-sequence, or there was an error reading
    // TODO: Handle these cases appropriately
}
```

I recommend you put all of this in a separate function.